# change the projct location

Tags: visual-studio-2008, file, directory, filepath

I have a visual studio 2008 project in the directory like

> C:\Users\espl\Desktop\hello\world\helloworld(.sln file)

Now I want the solution file in the directory like

> C:\Users\espl\Desktop\hello\helloworld(.sln file)

just outside the world folder.I just copy the project folder and paste it in required folder.but the modules are not loaded.So how it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

- Edit the file by hand. They're just text files
- Create a new blank solution and use "add existing project"
- Open the broken solution, remove all the broken projects, and add existing projects as per second option

I think I'd suggest the second option.